# UseQuery returns another useQuery's data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have many useQueries in one React component, some queries have a conflict with other queries.

These are my 2 queries which have a conflict:

```
export const GET_CONDITION_STATUS_QUERY = gql`
  query getConditionStatuses($name: String, $orderBy: [Option!]) {
    conditionStatuses(name: $name, orderBy: $orderBy) {
      id
      name
      idName
    }
  }
`;
```

```
export const GET_CONDITION_TARGETING_QUERY = gql`
  query getConditionTargetings($name: String, $orderBy: [Option!]) {
    conditionTargetings(name: $name, orderBy: $orderBy) {
      id
      name
      idName
    }
  }
`;
```

The problem is there when `conditionStatuses` are loaded in data, it returns normal `conditionStatuses's` data but after `conditionTargetings` are loaded, I get `conditionTargetings's` data in `conditionStatuses` useQuery.

Here is useQuery's code

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { ISelectData } from '@erp-client/components';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { GET_CONDITION_STATUS_QUERY } from '../gql/queries';

export const useConditionStatuses = (): [ISelectData[], boolean] => {
  const { loading, data } = useQuery<{ conditionStatuses: ISelectData[] }>(GET_CONDITION_STATUS_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      name: null,
      orderBy: [],
    },
  });

  return useMemo(() => {
    let conditionStatus: ISelectData[] = [];
    if (data && data.conditionStatuses) {
      conditionStatus = data.conditionStatuses.map(node => ({
        ...node,
        id: Number(node.id),
        value: Number(node.id),
        text: node.name,
      }));
    }
    console.log(data, 'conditionStatuses');
    return [conditionStatus, loading];
  }, [data, loading]);
};
```

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { ISelectData } from '@erp-client/components';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { GET_CONDITION_TARGETING_QUERY } from '../gql/queries';

export const useConditionTargetings = (): [ISelectData[], boolean] => {
  const { loading, data } = useQuery<{ conditionTargetings: ISelectData[] }>(GET_CONDITION_TARGETING_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      name: null,
      orderBy: [],
    },
  });

  return useMemo(() => {
    let conditionTargeting: ISelectData[] = [];
    if (data && data.conditionTargetings) {
      conditionTargeting = data.conditionTargetings.map(node => ({
        ...node,
        id: Number(node.id),
        value: Number(node.id),
        text: node.name,
      }));
    }
    return [conditionTargeting, loading];
  }, [data, loading]);
};
```

Here is screenshot with log in top `conditionStatuses` log you can see normal `conditionStatuses` data and bottom you will see `conditionTargetings` data

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6962834/80688537-0258c900-8add-11ea-98f1-9a24f1b30b46.png

Also, I try grouping these queries

```
query getConditionStatusTargetingType($name: String, $orderBy: [Option!]) {
    conditionTargetings(name: $name, orderBy: $orderBy) {
      id
      name
      idName
    }
    possibleStatuses(name: $name, orderBy: $orderBy) {
      id
      name
      idName
    }
    conditionTypes(name: $name, orderBy: $orderBy) {
      id
      name
      idName
    }
    productSettings(name: $name) {
      id
      name
      idName
    }
  }
```

Response is ok:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6962834/80703642-32f82d00-8af4-11ea-9035-f9cf1a2bf4b0.png

But console.log is strange:

```
const { loading, data: dataa } = useQuery<{
    conditionTypes: ISelectData[];
    possibleStatuses: ISelectData[];
    conditionTargetings: ISelectData[];
    productSettings: ISelectData[];
  }>(GET_CONDITION_TARGETING_STATUS_TYPE_PRODUCT_SETTINGS_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      name: null,
      orderBy: [],
    },
  });

  console.log(dataa);
```

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6962834/80703733-62a73500-8af4-11ea-8d64-3ce63ba8dfef.png

This is a very strange bug :(

Comment: the same `__typename` - results overwritten in cache - not bug - bad result types - not unique

Comment: Yes, that was a problem. Thank you